# Swift: frame vs bounds confusion with subviews and UIViews

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview

#### Situation:

I'm working on a custom control to display runways in an application.  The runway data (lat/lon) is converted into an XY grid in meters.  Then I make subviews that are rotated and placed appropriately in reference to an airport reference point.

#### View of Runways with x/y in meters

- `frame` (-957.794, 292.167, 1975.589, 1186.196)
- `bounds` (0,0,1975.589, 1186.196)

[image]

My ultimate goal is to embed these two subviews inside a custom UIView class - but I've run into issues with how to scale appropriately

#### Custom UIControl

- `frame` of (0,0,300,300)
- `bounds` of (0,0,300,300)

[image: desct]

This is the result of adding my two subviews to the custom UIControl.  Obviously not what I want to do.

I've tried the following which don't seem to work

- Changing the frame of my control to match the frame of red view
- Changing the bounds of my control to match bounds of the red view
- Applying a scale factor + translate to the Control

I know this should be something simple but I seem to have run up against a bit of a mental block.

## Sample Code from Playground

```
 /* - Define RUNWAY Geo DATA - */
let rwyGeo1 = RunwayGeoData(direction1: "8", lat1: lat1, lon1: lon1, direction2: "23", lat2: lat2, lon2: lon2)
let rwyGeo2 = RunwayGeoData( direction1: "13", lat1: 40.12317425, lon1:-76.30378541666667, direction2: "31", lat2:40.11767828333333, lon2:-76.29098628333334)

/* - Define Airport */
var KLNS : Airport = Airport(name: "KLNS - Lancaster", origin: CGPointMake(-76.2943611, 40.1223611))

/* - Add Runways to Airport - */
let rg1 : UIView = KLNS.addGeoRunway(rwyGeo1)
let rg2 : UIView = KLNS.addGeoRunway(rwyGeo2)

// Extract all the subviews + the boudning box
var (box, array) = KLNS.getSubViews()

// Create a temp view to hold runways
let redView = UIView(frame: box)
for v in array {
    redView.addSubview(v)
}
redView.backgroundColor=UIColor.redColor()
redView

redView.frame
redView.bounds

let blueView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(130.0,80.0,300.0,300.0))

for v in array {
    blueView(v)
}
blueView =UIColor.blueColor()

// Do some stuff here to fix the frame/bounds etc of BlueView...???
```